# Nested Case when statements in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, case, case-when

The following code creates as column called ‘Flagged’ in SAS:

```
Case When t3.Proportion=. then case when t3.'Standardised proportion'n >t1.SigmaMultiple Then 1 else 0  
End
Else 
Case When t3.Proportion=. and  abs(t3.'Standardised proportion'n) > t1.SigmaMultiple Then 1 Else 0
End
End
```

I'm trying to replicate it in python and usually I would have done a conditions code however the nested Case when aspect is confusing me.

The code i tried but didn't seem to be matching:

```
conditions =[
     ((dfSigmamissing['Proportion'] == 0) & (dfSigmamissing['SP'] > dfSigmamissing['SigmaMultiple'])),
       ((dfSigmamissing['Proportion'] == 0) & (dfSigmamissing['SP'] < dfSigmamissing['SigmaMultiple'])),
        ((dfSigmamissing['SP'].abs() > (dfSigmamissing['SigmaMultiple'])))
                ]

choices = [1,0,1]

dfSigmamissing['Flagged'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: hi @AndrewK, I'm not familiar with SAS but I tried to write an answer & explanations. Not sure if the output matches that of SAS, though. Can you please confirm if it matches? I might have understood mistakenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close I think, you need to remove the second condition from the `conditions` list, because if the first condition fails, `np.select` will fall back there. Otherwise, one of the first two conditions are (almost) always True since they are (almost) complementary. Also, we need
`dfSigmamissing['Proportion'] == 0` for the last condition, too:

```
conditions = [
     (dfSigmamissing["Proportion"] == 0) & (dfSigmamissing["SP"] > dfSigmamissing["SigmaMultiple"]),
     (dfSigmamissing["Proportion"] == 0) & (dfSigmamissing["SP"].abs() > dfSigmamissing["SigmaMultiple"])
]

choices = [1, 1]

default = 0

dfSigmamissing["Flagged"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default)
```

This works as:

- check first condition holds?

  -- if so put 1 in the corresponding row

  -- if not, go to second condition
- does the second condition hold?

  -- if so, put 1 in the corresponding row

  -- if not, fallback to default value, i.e., 0

To avoid repetition in the code, we can refactor some condition elements:

```
zero_prop = dfSigmamissing["Proportion"] == 0
sp = dfSigmamissing["SP"]
sigma_mul = dfSigmamissing["SigmaMultiple"]

conditions = [
    zero_prop & (sp > sigma_mul),
    zero_prop & (sp.abs() > sigma_mul)
]
```

which might increase readibility.

We can go even further and glue the first two conditions since both will output 1. This means we have 2 conditions now, so we can go for `np.where` which is this special case of `np.select`. Furhter, as far as I see, `sp > sigma_mul` is contained in `sp.abs() > sigma_mul`, so we can drop the former:

```
condition = zero_prop & (sp.abs() > sigma_mul)
dfSigmamissing["Flagged"] = np.where(condition, 1, 0)
```